# Question about problem 2.35 of PRML

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I looked for a solution to problem 2.35 of PRML(Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning), but there was a part I couldn't understand.
The solution is saying that:
$$\mathbb{E}[\Sigma_{\text{ML}}]\\={1\over N}\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[(x_n - \mu_{\text{ML}})(x_n - \mu_{\text{ML}})^T] \\= {1\over N}\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[x_nx_n^T-2\mu_{\text{ML}}x_n^T + \mu_{\text{ML}}\mu_{\text{ML}}^T]$$

But I can't understand why equality holds. Is $\mu_{\text{ML}}x_n^T$ equals to $x_n\mu_{\text{ML}}^T$?

Comment: PRLM ? Is it so tiring to write explicitly the title ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, the full name is "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Bishop. I thought writing the book's title was not necessary for my question. Next time writing a question, I'll avoid writing the abbreviation not everybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly one is the transpose of the other.

You can use $\mu_{\text{ML}}=\mathbb{E}[x_n]$ to show its expectation is symmetric, which is what you need here.

$$\mathbb{E}[\mu_{\text{ML}}x_n^T] = \mu_{\text{ML}}\,\mathbb{E}[x_n^T]= \mu_{\text{ML}}\,\mu_{\text{ML}}^T = \mathbb{E}[x_n]\, \mu_{\text{ML}}^T  = \mathbb{E}[x_n\mu_{\text{ML}}^T] $$

so your expression will become ${1\over N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[x_nx_n^T- \mu_{\text{ML}}\mu_{\text{ML}}^T]$ or ${1\over N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \mathbb{E}[x_nx_n^T] - \mu_{\text{ML}}\mu_{\text{ML}}^T$.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.

Comment: "One is the transpose of the other" and they are two ways to express the "*dot product*" of two vectors which is *commutative* ; I think it is appropriate to give the name of the operation which is at the heart of the question.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think from the context of $\Sigma_{\text{ML}}$ that this is supposed to be an estimator of the $n\times n$ covariance matrix, not the dot-product.